# How to make an alert if a particular condition is not met in java

Tags: java, swing, alert

I want my application to display an alert if the stock count is below the reorder level. The alert should function the same way security alerts do from most antivirus. By this I mean the alert should be at the right bottom corner and once it appears, the user can continue interacting with the application as the alert displays the message. The alert then disappears after some time, say 5 seconds. Anyone who can help me a way out...

Comment: What UI are working with? Swing? I have no suggestions, but that may drive suggestions :-)

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Swing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an icon in the system tray and tell it to show balloon messages with the desired information.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html

Answer (score 1):

You're basically looking for a tutorial on manipulating the system tray from Java.  This should do the trick nicely: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html